# fetching multiple columns of mysql table for each unique id and echoing the result in a single row of a HTML table for each unique id using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, multiple-columns

i want to fetch multiple columns of mysql table for each unique id and echoing the result in a single row of a HTML table  for each unique id.I am getting the result in the following form from the table ..

```
userid |  date         |   status
------------------------------------
1      |   28-06-17    |   1
------------------------------------
1      |   29-06-17    |   2
------------------------------------
1      |   30-06-17    |   0
------------------------------------
2      |   28-06-17    |   1
------------------------------------
2      |   29-06-17    |   2
------------------------------------
2      |   30-06-17    |  3
------------------------------------
```

Here is the code..just a basic php code to get the record from database..

```
if($con)
{
$query="SELECT * FROM `usersDetail` WHERE userid='$_POST["user_id"]'";
$result=mysqli_query($con, $query); 

    while($rowusersDetail=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {


            echo $rowusersDetail['userid']."<br>";
            echo $rowusersDetail['date']."<br>";
            echo $rowusersDetail['status']."<br>";


    }
}
```

*what i want is to generate html table using PHP to display all the Records of a
particular user into a single row..

```
userid |   28-06-17 | 29-06-17 | 30-06-17
_________________________________________
1      |         1  |         2|   0
_________________________________________
2      |         1  |         2|   3
_________________________________________
```

kindly please Help..thanks

Comment: can you show us your query?

Comment: search `pivot`.

Comment: @Jenish ,here the code..

if($con)
{
$query="SELECT * FROM `usersDetail` WHERE userid='$_POST["user_id"]'";
$result=mysqli_query($con, $query);  

    while($rowusersDetail=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {


            echo $rowusersDetail['userid']."<br>";
            echo $rowusersDetail['date']."<br>";
            echo $rowusersDetail['status']."<br>";


    }
}

Comment: @egom Just try the below answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is can be done with the help of **foreach** loop.

For that you need to retrieve all data at a time then you can manipulate the data with your requirement.

You can do like this

If your data is like

```
$data=[['userid'=>1,'date'=>'21-03-2017','status'=>2],
['userid'=>2,'date'=>'21-03-2017','status'=>1],
['userid'=>1,'date'=>'22-03-2017','status'=>6],
['userid'=>2,'date'=>'22-03-2017','status'=>7],
['userid'=>1,'date'=>'24-03-2017','status'=>2],
['userid'=>2,'date'=>'24-03-2017','status'=>6]];
```

Then

```
$finalData=[];
foreach ($data as $stats){
    $finalData[$stats['userid']][$stats['date']]=$stats['status'];
}
foreach ($finalData as $id=>$value){
    echo 'userId->'.$id;
    echo '<br>';
    foreach ($value as $date=>$status){
        echo $date.' -> '.$status; echo '<br>';
    }
    echo '<br>';
}
```

It will give out put as

[image]

I thing it will work for you.

Comment: Okay did you try this ?

Comment: i have tried and it's not working...not getting output like yours.
but getting like this

userId->1
1 -> 1
userId->2
2 -> 2